# Old Boss Returning at Place of Work

Tags: professionalism, ethics, relationships

Guys recently my current boss "Kate" annouced a train at work prorgram within our department. Though the department has a lot of enployees now it wasn't always that way. Few months ago me and another employee were the only ones in the department. Our boss at the time "Adam"  worked with us for 2.5 months before he left us. We were left assignment less and direction less for almost 2 months before Kate was hired. Now the thing is Kate somehow found Adam and wants him to come back to train us. Although the new employees won't know Adam and vice versa, i know Adam and now I'm confused on what to do?  Do i confront him and demand a explanation for his absentness or do i act as if nothing happened. I don't want Kate or Adam to feel awkward or ruin their friendship. Please tell me what to do?

Comment: Why does Adam owe you an explanation?

Comment: What makes you think you have standing to confront him?  His career is his to manage.  The company's staff is theirs to manage.  Who are you, again?

Comment: Sorry but your question and your nickname sounds like water cooler gossip.

Answer (score 5):

Your boss has made a decision, you need to comply with it without making waves or antagonising people.

Nothing constructive will come of 'confronting' your ex boss, so don't do it. Just concentrate on your work professionally and get what benefit you can out of the training. I've worked with many people whose competence and professionalism I have doubts about quite cheerfully, it wasn't my decision to have them there so I just make the best of it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an uncommon occurrence, especially at management levels.

People leave from management positions and then later come back as consultants or actually get rehired as managers or advisers because they have special knowledge or experience that has value to the company.  Simply put, unless you are an Executive-level employee, you have no standing to demand anything from a rehire.

If you were friendly enough at one point, you can certainly ask what happened and where he has been, but "Adam" is under no obligation to explain himself to you.  Your role is to follow the directions of your manager, and if she expects you to listen to Adam, you don't really have a choice (unless, of course, you want to change jobs).